Prove that it is always possible for them to join the line so that the number of men in front of them is equal to the number of women behind them
From the 2011 South African Junior Olympiad:
Several people line up in single file. A solitary latecomer wishes to join the queue. Prove that it is always possible for them to join the line somewhere so that the number of men in front of them is equal to the number of women behind them.
Assume the line consists only of women and men (no children, no pets, no aliens, no robots, ...)

Don't think the strategy tag is necessary. If the question was framed to ask what the latecomer should do to achieve a certain outcome, sure, but they just happen to join the queue somewhere without planning to make "the number of men in front of them equal to the number of women behind them" or the opposite.

The assumption seems unnecessary, you can totally ignore dogs and just file either behind or in front of one for example.

@Nautilus the question is what the person should do, not whether they will always by chance file at the right position.

It's not "chance", but it's not intentional strategy either. By this logic, lots of proof questions would be "strategy".

@DonQuiKong On the other hand, the assumption does make the position unique


 Suppose there are $w$ women in the queue. The latecomer should place themselves after the first $w$ people in the queue.


 To see why, let's start with the case that the first $w$ people in the queue are women, so that there are no men ahead of the latecomer in the queue, and no women behind them. These are obviously equal.


 Typically though there will be fewer than $w$ women in the first $w$ people. Those $n$ other women will be behind the latecomer in the queue, while their $n$ spaces are now taken up by men, so that the number of men ahead is still the same as the number of women behind.


+1 This is an amazingly great answer.

It is. This one (but not most of the others) relies on there being only men and women in the line. But it presents a much stronger claim than asked for: that there is precisely one place, and that it's a known number rather than something you have to iterate to and that might depend on the initial order of people in the line..

Call the number of men in front of you $M$, the total number of men $M_{total}$, the number of women behind you $W$, and the total number of women $W_{total}$.

Start at the back of the line. As you move to the front one person at a time, $M$ will count every integer from $M_{total}$ to $0$, and $W$ will count every integer from $0$ to $W_{total}$, with only one of $M$ or $W$ changing at each step. At some point, $M$ must count down to the current value of $W$, or $W$ must count up to the current value of $M$, since the counting sequences must "pass" one another and cannot skip any integers. Basically, as long as $M>W$, we can advance through the line to either decrease $M$ by $1$ or increase $W$ by $1$, and we can always repeat this until $M$ and $W$ are equal.


This answer is the easiest to understand. You got my vote. Also, the only one that doesn't have the new guy skip the line, which is also polite.

@MindwinRememberMonica - Oh yes, repeatedly tapping the woman in front of you on the shoulder and telling her "Excuse me, but there are too many women in front of me, so I need to be in front of you" is very polite.

@PaulSinclair I expect that each participant has signed a release form stating they agree to do the experiment, and that it has been reviewed by the ethic board as being non-offensive.

An alternative proof formulation which is pleasingly short and simple:

 The quantity of interest is $x=M_f-W_b$ (difference between the number of men in front, and woman behind, the latecomer). At the start of the line, $x<=0$ ($M_f =0$). Similarly, at the back, $x>=0$. $x$ can change by at most 1 for each place you move along the line. Thus, by a discrete version of Intermediate Value Theorem, $x=0$ for some place in line.


can we have a link to the theorem? For the layperson? EDIT: Welcome to Puzzling, Adam_Q

https://anuragbishnoi.wordpress.com/2015/06/25/discrete-version-of-the-intermediate-value-theorem/ @MindwinRememberMonica

@AriBrodsky my comment above contains a Wikipedia link to the theroem. I told Adam_Q to add the link to his answer.

In fact, $x$ always increases by exactly 1: if consideration moves past a man, then $M_f$ increases by one and $W_b$ stays the same; whereas if consideration moves past a woman, then $M_f$ stays the same and $W_b$ decreases by one.

Done! Thanks for the suggestion @Mindwin Remember Monica

But the link provided goes to the Intermediate value theorem, without any mention of a discrete version.  The link I included actually discusses a discrete version, which is what this answer refers to.

An alternative proof:

 In this queue, arguing that the number of men in front of the newcomer ($m_f$) is never equal to the number of women behind them ($w_b$) is the same as saying $m_f+w_f ≠ w_f+w_b$ is always the case, but it's clear that the number of people ahead of the newcomer can be equal to the total number of women.


this seems to be the same as Neil's answer

I posted mine before them.

+1 This simple evident argument, IMO, covers it all, even if perhaps it could have been phrased other way.


 Suppose the queue contains $w$ women and $m$ men, for a total of $p=w+m$ people. Then, consider the function $f(x)$ that takes a position in the queue $0 ≤ x ≤ p$ (where $0$ is before the start of the queue and $p$ is after the end) and outputs the number of women after that position, minus the number of men before that position.


 At $x=0$, there are $w$ women after that position, and 0 men before that position, so $f(0) = w - 0 = w$. At $x=p$, there are $m$ men before that position, and $0$ women after that position, so $f(p) = 0 - m = -m$.


 Now, consider what happens as we move from position $x$ to position $x+1$:
 If the $x$th person in the queue is a man, then the amount of men before that position increases by $1$, so $f(x)$ decreases by $1$.
Otherwise, if the $x$th person in the queue is a woman, then the amount of women after that position decreases by $1$, so $f(x)$ decreases by $1$.
So either way, $f(x + 1) = f(x) - 1$.


 As $f(0) = w$, and $f(x + 1) = f(x) - 1$, by induction $f(w) = 0$, so the person can insert themself at the $w$th position in the queue and have the number of men in front equal the number of women behind.



Prove that it is always possible for them to join the line somewhere so that the number of men in front of them is equal to the number of women behind them.

Not only is it always possible, but...

 ...the position in the line is always the same as the number of women in the line, regardless of the number of men and regardless of the order the line is in.

Proof (using 0 for men, 1 for women):

 Assume the line is ordered so that it consists of all the men followed by all the women, i.e. 0...01...1
The challenge is to divide the line so that there are the same number of 0s to the left as there are 1s to the right.
If N is the number of 0s and M is the number of 1s, the place to divide the line is always position M.  (It would be position N if women were ordered first):
If N > M we need to have M 0s to the left of the divide, to match the M 1s on the right of the divide: 000-00111
If M > N we need to have N 1s to the right of the divide, to match the N 0s on the left of the divide: 00011-111.  This is equivalent to M digits to the left of the divide.
If M = N then the divide must be in the middle: 000-111
As the problem just looks at the count of people on each side of the boundary, the order of each side doesn't matter.  Therefore the only alternative orderings that matter are the ones that require that one or more people are moved from one side of the boundary to the other.
Moving someone across the boundary means we are either moving someone who was being counted into the pool of people who are not being counted (e.g. moving a 0 from left to right) or moving someone who wasn't being counted to the pool of people who are being counted (e.g. moving a 0 from right to left).  This means that moving a single person will change the weighting on each side of the boundary (as well as moving the boundary position).
In order to compensate and keep the totals matching, you therefore need to do a swap; If you move a 1 from left to right, you need to move a 0 from right to left, and vice versa.
As all possible combinations can be derived by starting with the ordered line and moving individual people, and because any move necessitates a swap in order to keep the line balanced, we can see that the position of the boundary won't move, regardless of the ordering of the line.


Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!


 The newcomer counts the total # of women in the line.
 Let’s call this $WOMEN_{total}$.

 Then the newcomer starts at the front of the line and moves towards the back of the line until the number of people they have passed is $WOMEN_{total}$.

Why does this work?

 After squeezing into the line:

 Let $MEN_{front}$ be the # of men in front of the newcomer.
 Let $WOMEN_{front}$ be the # of women in front of the newcomer.

 Since $MEN_{front} + WOMEN_{front} = WOMEN_{total}$,
$WOMEN_{front} = WOMEN_{total} - MEN_{front}$.

 Now let $WOMEN_{behind}$ be the # of women behind the newcomer.

 Since $WOMEN_{front} + WOMEN_{behind} = WOMEN_{total} $,
$WOMEN_{behind} = WOMEN_{total} - WOMEN_{front}$.
 Also $WOMEN_{behind} = WOMEN_{total} - (WOMEN_{total} - MEN_{front})$
 Also $WOMEN_{behind} = MEN_{front}$.

  Therefore the newcomer has positioned themself so that the number of men in front of them equals the number of women behind them.


Another method, merely to prove that a solution exists: If the newcomer joins at a random position, the number of men in front might differ from the women behind. If it is always possible to reduce this number by one by moving one position forwards or backwards, then a solution must exist, as the difference will sooner or later become zero (for example, if there were cases where moving one position would change the difference by two, there might not exist a solution if the difference was an odd number).
If the number of men in the front is smaller than the number of women behind, then we take one step backwards.

If there was a woman behind us, then the number of women behind would decrease but the number of men in front would not change: the difference decreases by one.
If there was a man behind us, the number of men in front would increase by one, but the number of women behind would not change: again, the difference decreases by one.

Similarly, if the number of men in the front was larger, then we move one by one forwards, with similar effects.
To show that we won't reach the front or the end of the line before the difference can drop to zero, we can check what happens at the front or the back, and the same logic works there too: for example if we are at the front, the number of men in front of us cannot possible be larger than the women behind.


 Below is a mathematical proof using bijection, injection and surjection.


 Warning: I use position as a synonym for index, where indices start from 0. This implies that position n has n positions before it.


 Notation: wa = woman after, was = the set of women after, mb = man before, mbs = the set of men before, ws = the set of all women, ms = the set of all men, #xs stands for the number of elements of xs.


 Proposition: The position p for the latecomer to join is the one with #ws positions before it. Proof: If mbs is empty, then was is also empty and #mbs equals #was If mbs is not empty, then there exists a function from was to mbs. The proof then follows from the lemma below.


 Lemma: The function from the proposition above is a bijection between was and mbs. Proof(by contradiction): Assume that the function is not injective. This implies that there are two wa's mapped onto one mb. In that case #ws would be too large. Assume that the injection is not surjective. In that case the position is one with more than #ws positions before it. qed


 FWIW, you can find Haskell code here that moves the latecomer to the correct position. The code uses fixed point technology.



 Let $M$ be the number of men. Let $W$ be the number of women.
 If $M = 1$ and $W = 1$ the problem is trivial.
 Suppose this to be true for $M$ and $W$. Now suppose a male newcomer joins the file, and now our latecomer must join the file.
 The latecomer chooses the position that would be the solution for the $(M, W)$ pair. The new male comer is either in front of him or behind him.
 If the new male comer is behind him, we're done. If he's in front of him, then there's one more male in front of our latecomer than behind them. Let the latecomer get immediately in front of the person immediately in front of them (so they step up one position).
 If the person in front of our latecomer is a woman, then now there's one more woman behind them and we're done. If it is a man, then there's one less man in front of him and we're done.
 This is similar if a woman arrives.
 Since any file can be iteratively constructed by addition of men and women, this proves the statement.

This also provides an algorithm to find the solution to any state in O(N) where N is the number of people in the file.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

thank you! cool problem i now incorporate it to my dinner with friends repertoire

The following puzzles might be good for your dinner with friends:  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A80061+beginner

We can prove by induction.
In the base cases, we either have no women or no men. If we have no women, then the latecomer joins in the very front, because they have zero men in front of them and zero women behind them (since there are none to begin with). Similarly, if we have no men, then they join in the very back, because they have zero women behind them and zero men in front of them.
Now, assume that such a location exists given a line of m men and w women.

If we add one woman in front of the latecomer's location or one man behind their location nothing changes.

If we add one man in front of their location, there is now one more man in front of them than there are women behind them. Therefore, let's move the latecomer's location one spot ahead in the line. (This spot is guaranteed to exist because we just added a person to the front of the line.) Now, either one man who was previously ahead of them is now behind them (undoing the addition of the man in front) or one woman who was previously ahead of them is now behind them (balancing out the new man in front with a woman in back). In either case, their location remains balanced.

Very similar logic works for adding one woman behind their location — if we move the latecomer's location one spot behind, we either undo the effect of the extra woman or balance it out with an extra man.


In any case, the location exists for either m + 1 men and w women, or m men and w + 1 women. Therefore, by the inductive property, the location exists for any number of men and any number of women in the line.
